# Including Package "image_transport" in ROS2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem to include the package "image_transport" correctly.
This is my CMakeList:

---

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(camera_pkg)

## Default to C++14

if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED COMPONENTS
cv_bridge
image_transport
rclcpp
sensor_msgs
std_msgs
)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(cv_bridge REQUIRED)

add_executable(camera camera_pkg.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(camera rclcpp std_msgs OpenCV cv_bridge)

install(TARGETS
camera
DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

include_directories(
${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
${ament_cmake_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(camera
${OPENCV_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(camera
${OPENCV_LIBRARIES} ${ament_cmake_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(camera
${rclcpp_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(camera
${rclcpp_LIBRARIES} ${ament_cmake_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(camera
${sensor_msgs_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(camera
${sensor_msgs_LIBRARIES} ${ament_cmake_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(camera PUBLIC ${EXTRA_LIBS})

if(BUILD_TESTING)
find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()

---

My package.xml looks like this:

---

camera_pkg
  0.13.0
  Examples of minimal publisher nodes
  Shane Loretz
  Aditya Pande
  Apache License 2.0
  Mikael Arguedas
  Morgan Quigley
  Jacob Perron

<buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

<build_depend>rclcpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>OpenCV2</build_depend>
<build_depend>image_transport</build_depend>
<build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>

<exec_depend>rclcpp</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>OpenCV2</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>image_transport</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>cv_bridge</exec_depend>

<test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
<test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

ament_cmake

---

When I compile my code with the "colcon build" command I get this error:

undefined reference to `image_transport::create_publisher(rclcpp::Node*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, rmw_qos_profile_t)'

undefined reference to `image_transport::Publisher::publish(std::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::msg::Image_std::allocator<void > const> const&) const'

Can anyone help me what else needs to be added in the CMakeList and in the package.xml ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394998/including-package-%22image_transport%22-in-ros2/) by [SJeya](https://answers.ros.org/users/94759/sjeya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to add a

```
find_package(image_transport REQUIRED)
```

and add a

```
ament_target_dependencies(camera
    rclcpp
    sensor_msgs
    image_transport)
```

Note that it's recommended to use the `ament_target_dependencies(...)` for ros2 packages vs using `target_link_libraries(...)`

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2022-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SJeya](https://answers.ros.org/users/94759/sjeya/) on 2022-02-05**:
I have added these lines. But I get a different error now:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package):
By not providing "Findimage_transport.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"image_transport", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "image_transport"
with any of the following names:

```
image_transportConfig.cmake
image_transport-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "image_transport" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "image_transport_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
If "image_transport" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

Do you know where the problem could be ?

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2022-02-05**:
Is the image transport package installed?